# Paste a block in "replace" mode

Tags: cut-copy-paste, visual-block

This is best explained with an example:

#### Start by block selecting some text:

[image: selected]

#### Yank and paste it somewhere else:

[image: after paste]

Note that the existing `x` characters were pushed over to the side, rather than being replaced.

#### Desired "Replace" Behavior

[image: desired]

Is there a command that achieves the above desired result?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's `:h put-Visual-mode`. Just select the visual block of the same dimension to make it work as one-to-one replace: <kbd>1</kbd><kbd>v</kbd><kbd>p</kbd>

Comment: Also, looks like `1vP` is repeatable, while `1vp` is not.